# No Sound / Dummy Output in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, hp

I know there are many questions related to this topic but I am facing some weird behavior. 

**System info:**
Laptop HP Probook 430 G4 
Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 dual boot. (but problem is only with Ubuntu while sound in Windows works good) 

**Problem Description:** 
On few reboots, in the "Output" tab of sound settings, "Dummy output" is displayed. Hence no sound. 
While on few reboots, I can see my audio device listed in the "Output" tab of the sound settings. Even then, I don't get sound from my browser or vlc player whatsoever. 
**Already Tried:**

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-'uname -r' 
>  sudo
>   modprobe snd-hda-intel 
>  rm -r ~/.config/pulse* 
>  pulseaudio -k

and also steps from: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure


**Additional Info:** 
output of "sudo lspci":

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02) 
>   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02) 
>   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) 
>   00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21) 
>   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21) 
>   00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21) 
>   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1) 
>   00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1) 
>   00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1) 
>   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21) 
>   00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21) 
>   00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21) 
>   01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15) 
>   02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59) 
>   03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

If any further details are needed, please let me know the command and I will update my question accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Ubuntu bug tracker is more appropriate place to report bugs.